# Using the default integer in MPI

Tags: fortran, mpi

If I want to use the 64-bit interface I can specify the `-i8` compiler Flag for ifort or `-fdefault-integer-8` for gfortran.

In MPI however MPI_INTEGER is defined as a fixed 32 bit integer: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFK3V_2.3.0/com.ibm.cluster.pe.v2r3.pe400.doc/am106_pmd.htm

If I have a simple call such as:

```
MPI_Bcast(buffer, count, MPI_DATATYPE, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
```

How can I pass `MPI_DATATYPE` such that it takes the default value? I.e. `MPI_INTEGER8` if `-i8` is set or `MPI_INTEGER4` if not?

I was considering doing it trough a constant, but I don't know what the type of `MPI_DATATYPE` is. Is it `integer(4)` just like `MPI_COMM_WORLD` is?

Edit: I just realized, that different MPI implementations behave differently:

```
program main
    use mpi
    integer(4)    :: sz
    integer(4)    :: ierr

    call MPI_Init(ierr)
    call MPI_Type_size(MPI_INTEGER4, sz, ierr)
    write (* ,* ) "4 =  ", sz
    call MPI_Type_size(MPI_INTEGER8, sz, ierr)
    write (* ,* ) "8 =  ", sz
    call MPI_Type_size(MPI_INTEGER, sz, ierr)
    write (* ,* ) "? =  ", sz
    call MPI_Finalize(ierr)


end program main
```

IntelMPI:

```
> $ ./bla.x                                                                               
 4 =             4
 8 =             8
 ? =             4
```

OpenMPI:

```
> $ ./bla.x                                                                               
 4 =                       4
 8 =                       8
 ? =                       8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"In MPI however MPI_INTEGER is defined as a fixed 32 bit integer" It is not. That only is true for that particular MPI library you link to. If you link true MPI answer, link to the official MPI specifications.

If you want to use special flags changing the default behaviour so drastically, you would have to compile the MPI library to know about that flags. The implementation may or may not support such a change, but theoretically it should be possible.

There are tutorials on the web that show such compilation for certain MPI implementations. Use your search engine to find links as http://diracprogram.org/doc/release-12/installation/int64/mpi.html http://linuxtoolkit.blogspot.cz/2013/08/building-openmpi-libraries-for-64-bit.html and others.

If you want to be portable without caring about the default integer the compiler decided to use today and needing to have the MPI library synchronized with that, just use integer variables with some fixed storage size like `integer(int32)` and `integer(int64)`. Those kind constants are defined in the `iso_fortran_env` module.

Or do not use/change these ugly flags so that you can be sure that the MPI library has the same settings as the compiler's default.

Comment: It turns out that newer versions of IFort actually switch form 4 to 8 byte as well. This only creates more problems. Is there any way to write code that works fine on both systems?

Comment: What do they switch to? Which versions? Of what?

Comment: This is not just the compiler version. The value of `MPI_INTEGER` is defined by the MPI implementation, NOT by the compiler.

Comment: I edited it in the top post. In ifort 2016 MPI_INTEGER is 4 byte with & without "-i8", but for 2018 it is 4 byte without and 8 byte with "-i8".

Comment: It is not just the compiler. The compiler does not know any such thing as `MPI_INTEGER`.

Comment: You are right. The difference was not due to the difference between ifort versions, but because I was using OpenMPI on one machine and IntelMPI on the other. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, and it can be changed when compiling the MPI library. But it is different for various MPI implementations.